# How to extract coefficients and powers from expressions with non integer powers?

Tags: expression-manipulation, coefficients

I want to extract coefficients and powers of the expression

$$3-2x+7x^{2.1}+x^{2.4}-5x^3$$

---

Code:

```
expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;
```

To get a result such as:

> {{0,3},{1,-2},{2.1,7},{2.4,1},{3,-5}}

I tried to use `Coefficient` but that didn't work.

Comment: In the special case where all exponents are rational you can do this. `In[54]:= expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;
Map[{# /. x -> 1, Exponent[#, x]} &, 
 Collect[Rationalize@expr, x, Plus, List]]

Out[55]= {{3, 0}, {-2, 1}, {7, 21/10}, {1, 12/5}, {-5, 3}}`

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;
Transpose[{Exponent[#, x], # /. x -> 1}] & /@ List @@ expr
```

> {{0, 3}, {1, -2}, {2.1, 7.}, {2.4, 1.}, {3, -5}}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code gives me more than one error:
Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {0,3} cannot be transposed. >>

Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {1,-2} cannot be transposed. >>

Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {2.1,7.} cannot be transposed. >>

General::stop: Further output of Transpose::nmtx will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Comment: @MohamedMostafa I removed the `Transpose`, and that fixed the issue and yields the same result as OP has.

Comment: Somehow both variations work for me. The one suggested by @March is indeed the better one. `{Exponent[#, x], # /. x -> 1} & /@ List @@ expr`

Answer (score 7):

```
ce = Apply[List/*Map[List]/*ReplaceAll[a_. x^b_. :> Splice @ {b, a}]/*PadLeft];


ce[3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3]
```

> ```
> {{0, 3}, {1, -2}, {2.1, 7}, {2.4, 1}, {3, -5}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

You may use pattern matching to achieve what you want:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;

expr /. Plus -> List /. {(x2_ : 1  ) Power[x_, x1_] :> {x1, x2}, 
  x1_ x :> {1, x1}, x_ /; NumericQ[x] -> {0, x}}

{{0, 3}, {1, -2}, {2.1, 7}, {2.4, 1}, {3, -5}}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
coefList = List @@ # /. #2 -> 1 &;

expList = Exponent[##, List] &;

expCoefList = Transpose @* Through @* {expList, coefList}
```

***Examples:***

```
expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;

coefList[expr, x]
```

> ```
> {3, -2, 7., 1., -5}
> ```

```
expList[expr, x]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2.1, 2.4, 3}
> ```

```
expCoefList[expr, x]
```

> ```
> {{0, 3}, {1, -2}, {2.1, 7.}, {2.4, 1.}, {3, -5}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I'd expand the exponents until they are integers:

```
expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;

expr /. x -> y^10 // PowerExpand // Rationalize
(*    3 - 2 y^10 + 7 y^21 + y^24 - 5 y^30    *)

CoefficientRules[%, y]
(*    {{30} -> -5, {24} -> 1, {21} -> 7, {10} -> -2, {0} -> 3}    *)
```

Answer (score 4):

*? Maybe*:

```
MapAt[Total@*(Exponent[#,x]&/@Variables[expr] #&),1]/@List@@@CoefficientRules[expr]


(* {{3.,-5.},{1.,-2.},{2.1,7.},{2.4,1.},{0.,3.}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Cases`:

```
expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;

Cases[Flatten@{List @@ expr}, s_ :> {Exponent[s, x], Rationalize[s /. x -> 1]}]

(*{{0, 3}, {1, -2}, {2.1, 7}, {2.4, 1}, {3, -5}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll`:

```
expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;

Transpose[List @@ expr /. s_ :> {Exponent[s, x], Rationalize[s /. x -> 1]}]

(*{{0, 3}, {1, -2}, {2.1, 7}, {2.4, 1}, {3, -5}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Direct pattern-matching solution:

```
expr = 3 - 2 x + 7 x^2.1 + x^2.4 - 5 x^3;

List@@expr /. {a_. x^b_. :> {b, a}, c_?NumberQ :> {0, c}}
```